# Update metadata on n amount of files at the same time programmatically, using SPListItem update methods or SPWeb update batch?

Tags: 2010, development, document-library, metadata, updatelistitems

I need to update meta data on multiple files that exist on my SharePoint 2010 site. When starting the method that will update the metadata i do not know how many file that will need to be updated, however I do not think there should ever be more than 30-40 files that needs to be updated at any one time in the same batch. A requirement is that the version of the file is not updated.

I could just run a SPListItem.SystemUpdate(false) on each file as i iterate through the files, however i just found that SPWeb has a ProcessBatchData(string) method is this one to prefer instead of doing a SystemUpdate in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way like SystemUpdate(false); or SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion() on ProcessBatchData according to sharepoint SDK.
As a workaround, you could try to turn off the version control temporarily.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80748556-fed3-4906-a4da-7483d37525d7/cannot-use-processbatchdata-without-increasing-version-of-processed-item)

Comment: Thanks, turning off the version control on the library even if it is temporarily is not an option, I will have to go with SystemUpdate(false). I found this post http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2011/06/09/list-item-performance-updating-large-lists/ about Batch update. The results suggest that it would not be good for me to use the SPWeb batch update as there is never enough document to update.

Answer (score 0):

SPWeb.ProcessBatchData processes batch updates significantly faster than individual updates. Use batch processing when updating a larger number of items. It will allow the database to process all your update requests at once and will significantly improve the overall performance of your SharePoint application.